# Trigger is not detecting Collisions with other colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject that I only want to collide with certain objects, I added a trigger and checked for `OnTriggerEnter`. However, the rocket doesn't detect collisions with the Turret Object.

*Thanks in advance for anyone who helps!*

***Rocket Script:***

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{

    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Collision Detected with" + other);
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        PlayerController.health -= 75.0f;
        Die();

    }

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Boss 1")
    {
        Boss1Controller.health -= 100;
        Die();
    }

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Turret")
    {
        Destroy(other);
    }
}
```

Comment: You destroy the `Collider2D` not the `GameObject`

Comment: So first one destroys the turret collider, all consecutive ones just go through since there's no collider anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out, it turns out that triggers don't work with `Edge Colliders2D` so I just used a `Polygon Collider2D` instead. The shape is isn't as perfect as before but it's good enough.

*Rookie Mistake, sorry.*